# Python for Maya - Slider color changer

Tags: python, user-interface, maya, mel

I wrote this little script in Python for Maya, where I have a slider that should change the background color of my iconTextButton. Running the script I don't have any warnings or errors, but it doesn't do what I explained above.

I can't figure out what is the problem, maybe it's that I'm trying to call a function inside another function? ( when I'm calling setColor() inside `s_off()`). If the problem is this how can I resolve it?

Here is the code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

class ColorChangeWin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buildWin()

    def buildWin(self):
        self.win = cmds.window(title="ColorChange")
        self.menuLayout = cmds.menuBarLayout()
        self.menu = cmds.menu(label="Window")
        self.menuItem = cmds.menuItem(label = "Close", command = partial(self.closeWin, self.win))
        self.mainlayout = cmds.columnLayout(adj = True)
        color = cmds.intSlider(min = 0, max = 3, value = 0,  step = 1, dc = partial(self.s_off), cc = partial(self.s_on), p = self.mainlayout)
        cmds.iconTextButton(w = 55, bgc = (0.467, 0.467, 0.467), p = self.mainlayout)
        cmds.showWindow(self.win)

    def closeWin(self, window = None, arg = None):
        if cmds.window(self.win, exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.win, window = True)


    def s_off(*args):
        panel = cmds.getPanel(withFocus=True)
        cmds.modelEditor(panel, e = True,  sel = False, m = False)
        return()
        setColor()

    def s_on(*args):
        panel = cmds.getPanel(withFocus=True)
        cmds.modelEditor(panel, e = True, sel = True, m = True)

    def setColor(*args):
        color_1 = cmds.intSlider(color, q = True, value = True)

        if color_1 == 0: 
            cmds.iconTextButton(e = True, bgc = (1, 1, 1))
        if color_1 == 1:
            cmds.iconTextButton(e = True, bgc = (0, 0, 1))
        if color_1 == 2:
            cmds.iconTextButton(e = True, bgc = (0.608, 0, 0.157))
        return 

ColorChangeWin()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two things :

- you are miss using classes, you should use self. when something is used somewhere else inside your ui as ie : window name, slider, colored button
- you are putting a return before you set the color so it will exit

/

```
from functools import partial
import maya.cmds as cmds

class ColorChangeWin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buildWin()

    def buildWin(self):
        self.win = cmds.window(title="ColorChange")
        cmds.menuBarLayout()
        menu = cmds.menu(label="Window")
        cmds.menuItem(label = "Close", command = partial(self.closeWin, self.win))
        main_layout = cmds.columnLayout(adj = True)
        self.color = cmds.intSlider(min = 0, max = 3, value = 0,  step = 1, dc = partial(self.s_off), cc = partial(self.s_on), p = main_layout)
        self.text_button = cmds.iconTextButton(w = 55, bgc = (0.467, 0.467, 0.467), p = main_layout)
        cmds.showWindow(self.win)

    def closeWin(self, window = None, arg = None):
        if cmds.window(self.win, exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.win, window = True)


    def s_off(self, *args):
        panel = cmds.getPanel(withFocus=True)
        cmds.modelEditor(panel, e = True,  sel = False, m = False)
        self.setColor()
        return

    def s_on(self, *args):
        panel = cmds.getPanel(withFocus=True)
        cmds.modelEditor(panel, e = True, sel = True, m = True)

    def setColor(self):
        color_1 = cmds.intSlider(self.color, q = True, value = True)

        if color_1 == 0: 
            cmds.iconTextButton(self.text_button, e = True, bgc = (1, 1, 1))
        if color_1 == 1:
            cmds.iconTextButton(self.text_button, e = True, bgc = (0, 0, 1))
        if color_1 == 2:
            cmds.iconTextButton(self.text_button, e = True, bgc = (0.608, 0, 0.157))
        return
ColorChangeWin()
```

Comment: This fails when any other panel other than a modelEditor is focused (doesn't work if scriptEditor is focused!).

Comment: ive supposed the modelEditor thing was part of something else in his script

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, just a few notes:

1. When you create your gui objects, don't forget to capture them as a variable and using `self` so that you can reference them later.
2. In you class, all of the method's first parameter should be `self`, unless you are purposely making it a static method (then you need to add the decorator). Have a quick Google search if you want to learn more.
3. No need to query the slider's current value in `setColor`, as its `changeCommand` already provides it in its argument.
4. Not too sure what's being accomplished in `s_off` and `s_on`. Since all the interface items have been stored with `self.` you can already reference them from any other method in the class.

Here's a working example:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial


class ColorChangeWin(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.buildWin()

    def buildWin(self):
        self.win = cmds.window(title="ColorChange")
        self.menuLayout = cmds.menuBarLayout()
        self.menu = cmds.menu(label="Window")
        self.menuItem = cmds.menuItem(label="Close", command=partial(self.closeWin, self.win))
        self.mainlayout = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
        self.color = cmds.intSlider(min=0, max=2, value=0, step=1, cc=partial(self.setColor), p=self.mainlayout)  # Add self.
        self.textButton = cmds.iconTextButton(w=55, bgc=(0.467, 0.467, 0.467), p=self.mainlayout)  # Capture in variable.
        cmds.showWindow(self.win)

    def closeWin(self, window=None, arg=None):
        if cmds.window(self.win, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.win, window=True)

    def setColor(self, color_1):  # Add self as first parameter. No need to query the slider's value, as the 2nd parameter already has it from its changeCommand.
        if color_1 == 0: 
            cmds.iconTextButton(self.textButton, e=True, bgc=(1, 1, 1))
        if color_1 == 1:
            cmds.iconTextButton(self.textButton, e=True, bgc=(0, 0, 1))
        if color_1 == 2:
            cmds.iconTextButton(self.textButton, e=True, bgc=(0.608, 0, 0.157))


ColorChangeWin()
```

Comment: I didn't know that maya ui ctrl were emitting their values :O